# Correct notation to combine functions in one function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a standard state-space representation of a nonlinear system

$$\dot{\vec{x}}(t) = \vec{f}(\vec{x}(t), u(t))$$

Expanded, this non-linear relationship looks like

$$\dot{\vec{x}}(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{a}(t)\\\dot{b}(t)\\\dot{c}(t)
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(a(t), \mu(t))\\
f_2(b(t), c(t), \gamma(t))\\
f_3(b(t), c(t), \gamma(t))
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And there's some supporting functions

\begin{align} \mu(t) &= f_4(u(t)) \\
\gamma(t) &= f_5(\mu(t), a(t), b(t), c(t))\end{align}

**Question:**
How do I write that all functions $f_1$ to $f_5$ make up function $f$?

With union? Something like $f = f_1 \cup f_2 \cup\cdots \cup f_5$?

I also saw something like $f=\bigcup\{f_i:i\in\{1,2,\cdots, 5\}\}$

(Or is this not required?)

Comment: What do you mean by "make up $f$"?  Do you just mean the coordinates of $f$ as a vector?

Comment: @EricWofsey I see you removed the tag `set-theory`. Please explain that? Seeing I want to make a set of functions, I thought I had to use set theory.

Comment: The vast majority of questions that involve sets do not belong under the set-theory tag.  Please read the tag description (not just the name) to determine whether a tag is relevant before using it.

Comment: @EricWofsey OK thanks. Do you think another tag would be more fitting?